# the problem with the code of a simple telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from pytube import YouTube
import aiofiles
import aiohttp

TOKEN = '...'

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Отправь мне ссылку на видео с YouTube, и я скачаю его для тебя.")

@dp.message_handler()
async def download(message: types.Message):
    url = message.text
    video = YouTube(url)
    stream = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    filename = stream.default_filename

    await message.reply("Скачиваю видео...")
    stream.download(filename=filename)

    await message.reply("Отправляю видео...")
    async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'rb') as video_file:
        await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

.........

```
D:\prog\p\installer_YT_INST\.venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\prog\p\installer_YT_INST\download.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\prog\p\installer_YT_INST\download.py", line 9, in <module>
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: I don't believe `Dispatcher()` is supposed to take `bot` as an argument.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: if u make Dispatcher(), then there will be such an error: File "D:\prog\p\installer_YT_INST\download.py", line 11, in <module>
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^=
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: It seems like there's an [example](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/#simple-usage) in the docs that shows how to initialise the `Dispatcher()` have you tried that?